# How do i retrieve a value output from a stored procedure using: OUTPUT INSERTED.BrandDrugDetailsID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BrandDrugDetailsInsert]
    @BrandDrugDetailsID uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
    @BrandDrugID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Pharmacy_BrandDrugDetails(BrandDrugID) OUTPUT INSERTED.BrandDrugDetailsID
    VALUES (@BrandDrugID)
END
```

Anytime I try to retieve the value "@BrandDrugDetailsID" using:

```
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@BrandDrugDetailsID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
.
.
.

identity = new Guid(param[0].Value.ToString());
```

I get a null value.

If I try to execute the stored procedure in SQL Server itself, three values are returned:

- BrandDrugDetialsID = "471D08BA-382B-4F83-BECC-F96FEF84B5A5"
- @BrandDrugDetialsID = NULL
- Return Value = 0

I can't figure out what im doing wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that when you use the OUTPUT clause in a INSERT statement, the rows come back as a resultset.  So instead of using an OUTPUT parameter in the stored procedure, just run YourSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), and BrandDrugDetailsID will come out.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything with the INSERTED.BrandDrugDetailsID bit that would actually place it in the @BrandDrugDetailsID variable. You'll either have to OUTPUT into a table variable and then write the value manually to @BrandDrugDetailsID, or simply use ExecuteScalar to access the single value your procedure currently returns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your stored proc is working. How is the value of `INSERTED.BrandDrugDetailsID` making it into your output parameter `@BrandDrugDetailsID`?

```
DECLARE @TableVar Table (@NewBrandDrugDetailsID uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO Pharmacy_BrandDrugDetails(BrandDrugID) OUTPUT INSERTED.BrandDrugDetailsID INTO @TableVar
    VALUES (@BrandDrugID)

SELECT @BrandDrugDetailsID = @NewBrandDrugDetailsID FROM @TableVar
```

** Disclaimer, I've not tested this ! **

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Entityframework 6 or below, all you need to do is this:

```
   using (var db = new AppEntity) 
      {
         var BrandDrugDetailsID = db.BrandDrugDetailsInsert(BrandDrugID).FirstOrDefault();
      }
```